# Php - Do I need the modulus operator for this?

Tags: php

I can't wrap my head around this one. I've given myself hours of trial and errors
lol, so i'm coming to this great community for some expert help!  I'm fetching data from mysql and I wanna have `$result2` output in every 3rd position.

What am I doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
$result1 = $mysqli->query("SELECT name, age, car, FROM table1");
$result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT name, age, car, FROM table2");

$counter = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    $counter++;

    if($counter % 3 == 0) {
        while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $records[] = array('tags' => array($row2));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I'm trying to output:

```
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Bob",
            "age": 22,
            "car": "Ford",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Eric",
            "age": 24,
            "car": "Telsa",
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Steve",
            "age": 39,
            "car": "GMC",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            DISPLAY TABLE 2 RESULTS HERE
        }
    ]
},
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Tim",
            "age": 34,
            "car": "Jeep",
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Sam",
            "age": 44,
            "car": "Acura",
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Tim",
            "age": 34,
            "car": "Telsa",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            DISPLAY TABLE 2 RESULTS HERE
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Mike",
            "age": 33,
            "car": "POS",
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Tim",
            "age": 19,
            "car": "Saturn",
        }
    ]
},
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            "name": "Trish",
            "age": 64,
            "car": "BMW",
        }
    ]
},    
{
    "tags": 
    [
        {
            DISPLAY TABLE 2 RESULTS HERE
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Why do you have 2 tables with the same structure? That seems like a bad design.

Comment: I'm sure it is. This is a very small project that isn't really a big deal. I will look into that. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: _"DISPLAY TABLE 2 RESULTS HERE"_ - Do you want all the content from `table2` to be inserted in every third position or just one at a time?

Comment: Hey @MagnusEriksson thanks for replying. Yes, I want all the content from table2 to be inserted in every third position :)

Comment: What are you currently getting with your code.

Comment: @TobyOkeke thanks for the reply! The if($counter % 3 == 0) { ... runs once (stops at the first 3rd position) and doesn't continue on but the rest of table1 outputs

Comment: Fetch table 2 first, store it, release it, then put that array in with the fetch of table 1. Yes, use modulus to determine when you're on the third. You shouldn't keep the table2 fetching, it isn't needed.

Comment: @user3783243 i'm not sure I follow....

Comment: You are making `mysql` do more work than it needs to. You don't need `while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {` multiple times (unless the DB is being updated during this, but in that case you're going to have the wrong results from the first execution anyway). Run it once before the first table and store it to as an array `$results[] = ` or something like that, then use that array in the table 1 fetch.

Comment: The first time you go through the `result2` loop, it's going to read all the results from the second query. When you do it again, there won't be any more result rows to fetch, so the loop will end immediately.

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you! Makes total sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will only read from `table2` once. The second time it gets to the `while($row2 = $result2->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {` loop, there won't be anything left to read from `result2`, so the loop will end immediately.

Read all the results from `table2` into an array. Then after every 3 elements of `table1`, merge in those results.

```
$records2 = array();
while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records2[] = array('tags' => array($row2));
}

$counter = 0;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $records[] = array('tags' => array($row));
    $counter++;

    if($counter % 3 == 0) {
        $records = array_merge($records, $records2);
    }
}
```

BTW, you should use the constant `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQL_ASSOC` is for the obsolete `mysql_XXX` extension. Or just use the method `fetch_assoc()`.

Comment: Thank you kind sir! This worked perfectly and thank you for your feedback. I will look into things!